# Transform plugin vs Syntax plugin in Babel

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I want to use `Class properties` in my webpack setup.
Following along with this book (www.survivejs.com), I noticed the author adds 2 plugins to the `.babelrc` file: `babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties`as well as `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`.

Looking at the babel docs of the `syntax-class-properties` it states:

> Syntax only
>
> This plugin only allows Babel to parse this syntax. If you
>   want to transform it then see transform-class-properties.

What's the difference? And do I need both? My code seem to run fine just with the transform plugin.

Comment: Excellent question for the uninitiated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The transformation is a three step process:

1. Parse the source code into an AST
2. Change / transform the AST
3. Print the AST (convert to source code)

**Syntax** plugins are necessary for step 1: Proposals such as class properties introduce a new syntax, which cannot be parsed by current JavaScript parsers. Syntax plugins extend the parser so it understands the new syntax.

Example: Imagine I introduce a new token `@`, such as in

```
@.foo();
```

A JavaScript parser wouldn't be able to parse this code into an AST, because currently the `@` is invalid in that position. So I'd have to extend the parser to parse it.

**Transform** plugins are necessary for step 2: Now that the source was parsed, we need to convert the AST nodes of the new feature into something that is valid in current JavaScript.

Example: The `@` in my previous example is a new way to refer to `this`. To make it work in current environments which don't understand `@`, I need to transform and replace it with `this`, so that the above example becomes

```
this.foo();
```

> And do I need both?

If you want to convert your code to ES5, yes.

> My code seem to run fine just with the transform plugin.

You might be using a preset of something that already includes the syntax plugin.

Comment: Is there ever a time when you would use the syntax plugin, but not the transform plugin? I'm curious as to why they're individually downloadable.

Comment: Maybe you want to use Babel for something else than converting your code to ES5 (e.g. just running a custom plugin), but you still want it to be able to parse that syntax.

Comment: Ah makes sense thanks! Do you have any examples of something like this? It'd be nice to see the use case in a more concrete manner.

Comment: It's still using Babel5, but I disabled all transforms explicitly (so same use case): https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift/blob/dd2acd163497e68b06e960cabf5bff470fb56a61/src/template.js . Here I am parsing a piece of JS code, which has dynamically named identifiers injected into it. The custom plugin finds those identifiers and replaces it with AST nodes. The whole function is for being able to inject AST nodes via template literals: ```var node = statement`var something = ${someOtherNode};`;```.

Comment: I guess in that specific case (class properties), omitting the transforms only makes sense if you don't want to execute the code, but rather build a tool that does something with the AST (other code transforms, linting, static analysis, etc).

Comment: Really appreciate the effort you put into these comments. Thanks!

Comment: For those who don't know AST stands for [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)

Comment: What does AST stands for?

Comment: @ZahidSaeed: See the comment directly above yours :)

Answer (score 5):

If you look at https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#transform it says

> Transform plugins will enable the corresponding syntax plugin so you don't have to specify both.

Although maybe should add that in all the syntax plugins? Feel free to bring up an issue/PR for it.